# Aeron MDC (Multi-Destination-Cast) performance

Tags: aeron

I'm playing with Aeron mdc and find that the publication performance degrades with the increase of subscribers before reaching the network capacity.

The case is that 1 publication in 1 node,  sending data with speed 150MB/s  and 3 subscribers in another 4 nodes receiving the data, the network capacity is 2GB/s.

When adding more subscribers, there will be backpressure and the sending speed will degrade. I suppose this should not exist before reaching the network capacity.

Is it a problem of Aeron? Or I'm doing wrong with it? How can I solve the problem, because I have more subscribers. Thanks very much for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of using MDC or not you need to correctly configure the buffer sizes to get optimal performance. I can see from your one subscriber figures that things are not optimal but this is beyond the scope of your question.

With MDC each receiver gets its own unicast stream. MDC can be used to simulate multicast in environments which do not support multicast. Each of these unicast streams consume part of the bandwidth and will ultimately saturate the outgoing link from the producer.

So in summary, MDC will consume bandwidth directly related to the number of receivers.

Comment: Thanks very much, after making aeron.mtu.length from default value to 8192, the performance improves a lot